# Problem incorporating data got from API vue.js

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js

After get API call with a string input attached, I get the result alright. The problem I have is incorporating it to my frontend. I have tried a lot of solutions that I found online but nothing working and cannot understand. So far I have done this:

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script type = text/javascript src = https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.min.js></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vue.resource/1.0.3/vue-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="http://127.0.0.1:1880/" target="_self">
    <label for="request"><strong>Please insert the input here:</strong></label><br>
    <input type="text" id="request" name="input"><br>
    <button v-on:click="getOverview($event)">Submit</button>
</form>
<h1 id="results" v-for="overview in overview">
    {{overview}}
</h1>
<script type = text/javascript >
    new Vue({
        el: "#results",
        data() {
            return {
                overview: []
            }

        },
        methods: {
            async getOverview(event) {
                try {
                    const {data:{json:{sub_regions}}} = await axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:1880/');
                    console.log('results data', sub_regions);
                    this.overview = sub_regions;
                }
                catch (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                    return [];
                }
            }
        },
        created(){
            this.getOverview()
        }
    })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am a bit lost with javascript as I am new to it, all kinds of help are welcome,
Thank you in advance! :)

EDIT: the file I get from the API is JSON

Comment: Try using separate names for array and element: `v-for="overview_item in overview"`

Comment: I also suggest you add `type="button"` to your `<button>` element

Comment: @ChrisG surprisingly, that doesn't appear to be a problem for Vue ~ https://jsfiddle.net/hwy3okna/

Comment: @Phil Yeah, it seemed unrelated to the error anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

Some problems here...

1. You're including Vue twice (`https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.min.js` and `https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js`). Don't do that
2. You cannot use a `v-for` directive on your root Vue element
3. Your form is outside your Vue root so you won't be able to use `v-on`
4. Your submit button will submit the form normally. There's nothing stopping that from happening
5. Your `input` value is never used. You should try binding it to a data property

Change your HTML to

```html
<div id="results">
  <form action="http://127.0.0.1:1880/" @submit.prevent="getOverview">
    <label for="request">
      <strong>Please insert the input here:</strong>
    </label> 
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="request" name="input" v-model="input">
    <br>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
  <h1 v-for="item in overview">
    {{ item }}
  </h1>
</div>
```

and in your JS, replace `data` with

```js
data: () => ({
  overview: [],
  input: ''
})
```

Then you can use `this.input` if you ever need to get the value the user types in.

Here's an example using a placeholder API

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#results",
  data: () => ({
    overview: [],
    input: ''
  }),
  methods: {
    async getOverview ($event) {
      let url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users'
      if (this.input) {
        url += `/${encodeURIComponent(this.input)}`
      }
      try {
        const { data: sub_regions } = await axios.get(url)
        console.log('results data', sub_regions);
        this.overview = Array.isArray(sub_regions) ? sub_regions : [ sub_regions ]
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        this.overview = []
      }
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.getOverview()
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<div id="results">
  <form action="http://127.0.0.1:1880/" @submit.prevent="getOverview">
    <label for="request">
      <strong>Please insert the user ID here:</strong>
    </label>
    <br>
    <input type="number" id="request" name="input" v-model.number="input">
    <br>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
  <h1 v-for="item in overview">
    {{ item.name }}
  </h1>
</div>
```

---

Other notes:

- Avoid using the same variable name for your array and iterable.

  - Bad - `v-for="overview in overview"`
  - Good - `v-for="thing in things"`
- [VueResource](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource) is long dead. Avoid using it or at least update to the latest version (1.5.1)

Comment: i did all this but still nothing, it rederects me to 127.0.0.1:1880/?input=*******  without showing any changes to the website

Comment: @Bernnt sounds like something else is going wrong. I bet there's some errors in your console

Comment: @Bernnt I've updated my answer with a runnable snippet and it works fine

Answer (score 1):

Looks as though you are trying to call a method outsides of the vue app itself.
You have the `el: "results"` but you are trying to invoke a vue method within your button outside of its context.

Try something like this:

```html
<div id="results">
  <form action="http://127.0.0.1:1880/" target="_self">
      <label for="request"><strong>Please insert the input here:</strong></label><br>
      <input type="text" id="request" name="input"><br>
      <button v-on:click="getOverview($event)">Submit</button>
  </form>
  <h1 v-for="overview in overview">
      {{overview}}
  </h1>
</div>
```